# Codeigniter 3.1 IFNULL and Coalesce not working?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm working on a upload image form that updates a record in database. The logic is `if (isset($valueofupload))` then update the record.

I tried to use `IFNULL` or `COALESCE` in Codeigniter, but it's not working.

Here's the code:

```
$row = $rs->row_array();

$sql = "UPDATE table
        SET location_pic = IFNULL(?, ?) WHERE event_id = ?"; 

$query = $this->db->query($sql, array($arr_newname['0'], $row['location_pic'], $id));
```

Comment: How it's not working? Please be more specific.

Comment: So what are the values of $arr_newname[0], $row['location_pic'] and $id?

Comment: if (isset($value)) then update .  that what I want. but if(isset) is not good for me because if I have 100 field input form  I need ot if(isset) 100 time?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague. But from what I understand, you want to update `location_pic` field of some event record with `$arr_newname['0']` or `$row['location_pic']` if the former is null. Why don't you try this instead?

```php
$row = $rs->row_array();

$sql = "UPDATE table SET location_pic = ? WHERE event_id = ?"; 

$query = $this->db->query($sql, [
    $arr_newname['0'] ?? $row['location_pic'], 
    $id // Probably $row->id ?
]);
```

Read more about null coalesce operator (`??`) in PHP 7:
https://secure.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php

Or if you want to update the record in case that `$arr_newname['0']` is set, why not:

```php
if (isset($arr_newname['0'])) {
    // ...

    $sql = "UPDATE table SET location_pic = ? WHERE event_id = ?"; 

    $query = $this->db->query($sql, [$arr_newname['0'], $id]);

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I know isset  but it's not good for the future. If I have 100 field   I need to if isset 100 field

Comment: But it's ok with you to perform 100 mysql queries that actually do not modify any data? BTW, you can use a `foreach` loop to iterate over the field names and check if they're set in one go, before issuing the query.